# Django 1.11 send file form (not required)

Tags: django, sendmail

Problem in sending a message that contains a file. At the moment when you attach a file, the letter comes to the mail with an attachment. It would seem all right if the field is required, but if the field is not mandatory and does not select the file to be sent, the letter does not come to the mail.
Who will tell me how to solve this problem?

#### Views:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    file_form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if file_form.is_valid():
        f_name = file_form.cleaned_data['f_name']
        f_mail = file_form.cleaned_data['f_mail']
        f_message = file_form.cleaned_data['f_message']
        f_news = file_form.cleaned_data['f_news']
        f_file = request.FILES['f_file']
        news = ''
        if f_news:
            news = 'Посетитель дал согласие на получение новостей'
        d = {'f_name': f_name, 'f_mail': f_mail, 'news': news, 'f_message': f_message}
        htmly = get_template('mail/file.html').render(d)
        plaintext = get_template('mail/file.txt').render(d)
        from_email = 'dolgoletie.plastic@yandex.ru'
        to_email = [from_email, ]
        subject = 'Страничная форма c файлом'
        html_content = htmly
        text_content = plaintext
        try:
            mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, to_email)
            mail.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
            mail.attach(f_file.name, f_file.read(), f_file.content_type)
            mail.send()
        except:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid mail send!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    file_form = FileForm()
```

#### ModelForm:

```
class FileForm(forms.Form):
f_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
f_mail = forms.EmailField(required=True)
f_message = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=500)
f_file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput)
f_news = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

#### Html Form:

```
<form class="form_question" role="form" method="post" action=" " {% if file_form.is_multipart %}enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row_block">
        <label for="f_name">
            <span class="form_title">Ваше имя</span>
            <input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="ФИО" required />
        </label>
        <span class="name_text">Для более точного ответа вы можете прикрепить фото, снимки УЗИ, анализ</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row_block">
        <label for="f_mail">
            <span class="form_title">Почта</span>
            <input type="text" name="f_mail" placeholder="Email" required />
        </label>
        <span class="upload_wrapper">
            <div class="fileform">
                <div class="selectbutton">Прикрепить файл</div>
                <input id="upload" type="file" name="f_file" required  />
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row_block">
        <label for="f_message">
            <span class="form_title">Вопрос</span>
            <textarea name="f_message" id="textform" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
        </label>
        <span class="wrapper_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="f_news" id="checkbox" value="a1" checked />
            <label for="checkbox"></label>
            <strong>Подписаться на новости и акции</strong>
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить" id="button_submit">
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Again. If you delete **required** and do not select a file, the message does not come. Obviously it is necessary to describe the processing. Tried an option:

```
if 'f_file' in request.FILES:
    f_file = request.FILES['f_file']
    return f_file
```

But I did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem of sending a file to the mail:

```
f_file = request.FILES['f_file']
```

Change to:

```
f_file = request.FILES.get('f_file', False)
```

And added verification before shipping:

```
if f_file:
    mail.attach(f_file.name, f_file.read(), f_file.content_type)
```